# Faster API for downloading 'just IDs' from O365 Exchange?

Tags: rest, outlook, office365

I am connecting to O365 Outlook Mail Get Messages REST API, e.g.

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$top=50&$select=Id
```

and I am trying to retrieve just IDs so I can determine if messages have been deleted from my inbox (e.g. diff'ing against a previous ID list).  I'm checking `@odata.nextLink` to perform a synchronous series of REST calls until complete.

I'm finding that this call has roughly the same performance as downloading the full message (e.g. without the $select clause), aka ~50 Ids / second.  I'd like to know if there is a more efficient / quicker way of retrieving just a list of Ids of all messages in the Inbox.  A call to retrieve a list of deleted/moved Ids from a point in time (e.g. tombstones) would also work, something like:

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$top=50&$select=Id&$filter=DateTimeTombstone gt 2014-09-01T00:00:00Z
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently there isn't. Sync is on our radar to add though, which sounds like it might help your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the REST API, but EWS lets you sync any Exchange folder - this way you will know which items were created/modified/deleted without loading **all** items in the folder - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ee693003(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I should have specified that I was looking for an answer via the REST API.